# How do you search for a specific word in a csv column using csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file from which I want to search through the text of only one column. Eg. If I have a line of text in the column "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and I search for "dog" in the "text" column, I should print that row. Here's what I have been trying to improve on so far.

```
def read(option, searchitem):
    if option == "text":
        csvfile=open('myfile.csv','r')
        for row in csvfile:
            if row[2].find(searchitem):
                print(row)
```

But all the rows in my file are being printed. I have tried looking through similar questions and applying them but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` returns the index in the string of the match if one is found, otherwise it returns `-1`. Both positive and negative numbers are considered `True` in Python, with `0` being the only number considered `False`. As such, `any_string.find(anyItem)` will always evaluate to `True` (hence all your lines being printed).

To check if a substring exists within another string (or is equal to it), you can use the `in` operator:

```py
if searchitem in row[2]:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This was why my earlier solutions were not working.

Answer (score 0):

I used Oliver's advice to improve upon my earlier soution and received desired results.

def read(option, searchitem):
    with open('text.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

```
    # get number of columns
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        array = line.split(',')
        first_item = array[0]

    num_columns = len(array)
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    included_cols = [4]

    for row in reader:
        content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)
        for item in content:
            if searchitem in item:
                print(row)
```